# Как сделать обработку событий клавиш

Tags: java, javafx, awt

Пытаюсь сделать примитивный кликер с помощью awt.Robot.
Не понимаю, как реализовать обработку события при нажатия на клавишу пробел, что бы происходил клик 
Вот тестовый код:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Robot robot;
    Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Кликер");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        robot = new Robot();


        scene = new Scene(layout, 200, 100);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();


    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(300);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(300);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы слушать нажатие определённой кнопки в JavaFX нужно воспользоваться библиотекой `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;


public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Robot robot;
    Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Кликер");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        robot = new Robot();

        scene = new Scene(layout, 200, 100);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        scene.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCharacter().equals(" "))
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                        robot.delay(300);
                        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                        robot.delay(300);
                    }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Вы не сможете ловить таким образом action кнопки (такие как Ctrl, Shift, функциональные кнопки и т.д.). Но `setOnKeyPressed` и `setOnKeyReleased` поймает их тоже. Так что, свободно заменяйте эту строку

```
scene.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
```

На эту

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
```

или эту

```
scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
```

А проверку на нажатие заменить такой строкой

```
if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F12"))
```

> "Key typed" events are higher-level and generally do not depend on the
>   platform or keyboard layout. They are generated when a Unicode
>   character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about
>   character input. In the simplest case, a key typed event is produced
>   by a single key press (e.g., 'a'). Often, however, characters are
>   produced by series of key presses (e.g., SHIFT + 'a'), and the mapping
>   from key pressed events to key typed events may be many-to-one or
>   many-to-many. Key releases are not usually necessary to generate a key
>   typed event, but there are some cases where the key typed event is not
>   generated until a key is released (e.g., entering ASCII sequences via
>   the Alt-Numpad method in Windows). No key typed events are generated
>   for keys that don't generate Unicode characters (e.g., action keys,
>   modifier keys, etc.).

[Официальная документация.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html)

Судя по вашей реализации, вы пытались сделать implement интерфейса `KeyListener` библиотеки `awt`. Но даже в этом случае, вам пришлось бы делать `Override` на все его 3 метода `keyPressed`, `keyReleased`, `keyTyped`.

Comment: Да, вы сделали именно то, что я хотел. Но теперь, вместо пробела нужно указать кнопку F12. Как это сделать? 
Если я напишу сюда if (ke.getCharacter().equals("F12")) это не срабатывает. Пробовал еще юникод, но тоже не получилось.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо.

Comment: Вы на тостере есть? Я там же задавал этот вопрос, если напишите этот ответ туда, поставлю его лучшим

Comment: @Владислав, я там практически не появляюсь. Но спасибо за предложение. :)